# Not translating key on model define unique custom error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, i18next

#### Problem

Using **18next.t** function to translate key, is getting me the generic sequelize unique constraint error message instead of defined custom message

#### Environment

sequelize@5.22.4

i18next@21.3.3

#### Model definition `candidate.js`

```js
...
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Candidate = sequelize.define('Candidate', {
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: [
        ...
      ],
    },
    docTin : {
    ...
      unique: {
        args: 'candidates_unique_doctin_company_unity',
        get msg() { return i18next.t('invalid-candidate-unique-doc-tin') }
      },
...
```

#### Result:

`docTin must be unique`

#### Expected:

`{Custom error message located on lang.json}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i founded was prototyping the main create function on model definition, to allow use functions on unique msg properties

```js
...
  const orgCreate = Candidate.create;
  Candidate.create = function(){
    return orgCreate
      .apply(this, arguments)
      .catch(err => {
        const uniqueErrorName = 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError'
        if (err.name === uniqueErrorName) {
          err.errors = err.errors.map(e => ({
            ...e,
            message: typeof e.message === 'function' ? e.message() : e.message
          }))
        }

        throw err;
      });
...
```

replacing

```js
get msg() { return i18next.t('invalid-candidate-unique-doc-tin') }
```

for

```js
msg: () => i18next.t('invalid-candidate-unique-doc-tin')
```